# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/test/context/TestContextAnnotationUtils in SOAP web service test

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, testing, integration-testing

I have generated SOAP web service in spring boot and the endpoint works fine.
Then I added some test for that endpoint and I get the following error stack while running the test:

```
21:33:51.263 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractContextLoader - Did not detect default resource location for test class [ms.template.XohksMxControllerTest]: class path resource [ms/template/XohksMxControllerTest-context.xml] does not exist
21:33:51.264 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractContextLoader - Did not detect default resource location for test class [ms.template.XohksMxControllerTest]: class path resource [ms/template/XohksMxControllerTestContext.groovy] does not exist
21:33:51.264 [main] INFO org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractContextLoader - Could not detect default resource locations for test class [ms.template.XohksMxControllerTest]: no resource found for suffixes {-context.xml, Context.groovy}.

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/test/context/TestContextAnnotationUtils

    at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.OverrideAutoConfigurationContextCustomizerFactory.createContextCustomizer(OverrideAutoConfigurationContextCustomizerFactory.java:41)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.getContextCustomizers(AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.java:404)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.buildMergedContextConfiguration(AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.java:376)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.buildMergedContextConfiguration(AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.java:294)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.buildTestContext(AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.java:108)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.buildTestContext(SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.java:101)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.<init>(TestContextManager.java:137)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.<init>(TestContextManager.java:122)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTestContextManager(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:151)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:142)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner.<init>(SpringRunner.java:49)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:70)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:37)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:70)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.createRunner(ClassRequest.java:28)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.MemoizingRequest.getRunner(MemoizingRequest.java:19)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:50)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:220)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:53)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.test.context.TestContextAnnotationUtils
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 26 more


Process finished with exit code -1
```

** The dependencies that I use are the following:**

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version "2.3.4.RELEASE"
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version "1.0.10.RELEASE"
    id 'java'
    id 'jacoco'
    id 'checkstyle'
}
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web-services'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation "junit:junit:4.13
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml'
   
    implementation "org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:4.0.0"
    implementation 'jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:4.0.0'
    implementation group: 'wsdl4j', name: 'wsdl4j', version: '1.6.2'
    implementation group: 'javax.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-api', version: '2.3.1'
    implementation group: 'javax.activation', name: 'activation', version: '1.1.1'
    implementation group: 'com.sun.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-impl', version: '2.3.1'
    implementation group: 'com.jcraft', name: 'jsch', version: '0.1.44-1'

    jaxb "org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-xjc:4.0.0"
    jaxb "org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:4.0.0"

    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    annotationProcessor 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor'

    testCompile group: 'org.powermock', name: 'powermock-api-mockito2', version: "2.0.7"
    testImplementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-test-autoconfigure', version: '2.6.5'
    testImplementation group: 'org.springframework.ws', name: 'spring-ws-test', version: '3.1.2'
    testImplementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-test', version: '2.3.4.RELEASE'
}
```

**The java code that I use for the test is the following:**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.core.io.ResourceLoader;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.springframework.ws.test.server.MockWebServiceClient;
import org.springframework.ws.test.server.RequestCreator;
import org.springframework.ws.test.server.RequestCreators;
import org.springframework.ws.test.server.ResponseMatcher;
import org.springframework.ws.test.server.ResponseMatchers;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = TemplateApplication.class, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = XohksMxControllerTest.class)
public class XohksMxControllerTest {


    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    private MockWebServiceClient client;

    @Autowired
    private ResourceLoader resourceLoader;

    @Before
    public void createClient() {
        Assertions.assertNotNull(applicationContext);
        client = MockWebServiceClient.createClient(applicationContext);
    }

    @Test
    public void mockServerCall() throws IOException {

        final RequestCreator requestCreator;
        final ResponseMatcher responseMatcher;

        client = MockWebServiceClient.createClient(applicationContext);

        Resource requestPayLoad = resourceLoader.getResource("requestPayload.xml");
        Resource responsePayload = resourceLoader.getResource("responsePayload.xml");

        requestCreator = RequestCreators
                .withSoapEnvelope(requestPayLoad);

        responseMatcher = ResponseMatchers.soapEnvelope(responsePayload);

        client.sendRequest(requestCreator).andExpect(responseMatcher);

    }

}
```

I tried to change the versions of spring-boot-starter-test dependency to make it same with the spring boot version (2.3.4.RELEASE), but it did not work.

Answer (score 2):

Adding  spring-test dependency solved the issue:
testImplementation group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-test', version: '5.3.8'